# Calculating tangent space of $x^{2}+y^{2}=z^{2}$ at origin

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

I am asked to show that the tangent space of  $M$={ $(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^{2}+y^{2}=z^{2}$} at the point p=(0,0,0) is equal to $M$ itself.

I have that $f(x,y,z)=x^{2}+y^{2}-z^{2}$ but as i calculate $<gradf_p,v>$ i get zero for any vector.Where am i making a disastrous error?

Comment: What's the _definition_ of the tangent space here? (Not a rhetorical question - since $M$ is not a manifold I have no idea what that definition might be...)

Comment: Given $M\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $p \in M$ the tangent space at the point p is defined by {$v\in \mathbb{R}^{n} : \exists\lambda:(-r,r)\rightarrow M$ with $\lambda(0)=p$ and $\lambda'(0)=v$} .Sorry i take quite long to type in latex

Comment: Ok. Then the error is you're assuming that if $v$ is orthogonal to the gradient of $f$ then $v$ is a tangent vector. That theorem has hypotheses that do not hold here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$M$ is homogeneous, in the sense that if $(x,y,z)\in M$ and $t\in\Bbb R$ then $(tx,ty,tz)\in M$.

If $v\in M$ then you can define $\lambda:\Bbb R\to M$ by $$\lambda(t)=tv.$$The homogeneity of $M$ shows that $\lambda$ actually is a map into $M$, and it's clear that $\lambda(0)=0$ and $\lambda'(0)=v$.

Conversely, suppose $\lambda:(-r,r)\to M$ is differentiable and $\lambda(0)=0$. Then $\lambda(t)-\lambda(0)\in M$. Since $M$ is homogeneous it follows that $$\frac{\lambda(t)-\lambda(0)}{t}\in M\quad(t\ne0).$$Letting $t\to0$ shows that $\lambda'(0)\in M$, since $M$ is closed.

Answer (score 1):

The curve $$\beta_\theta(s) = (s\sin\theta,s\cos\theta,s)$$ has for every $\theta\in\mathbb R$ an image inside of $M$ (you can prove this easily) and $\beta_\theta(0)=(0,0,0)$. For the derivative it holds
$$\beta_\theta'(s) = (\sin\theta,\cos\theta,1).$$
Thus $(\sin\theta,\cos\theta,1)$ is a tangent vector of $M$ at $(0,0,0)$, as well as every multiple of it. Thus,
$$T_{(0,0,0)}M \supseteq \{(t\sin\theta,t\cos\theta,t)\colon \theta,t\in\mathbb R\} \supseteq M,$$
where $T_{(0,0,0)}M$ is the set of all tangent vectors of $M$ at $(0,0,0)$.
The last inclusion can be seen easily.

For the other way around, you can take any tangent vector and find the
corresponding curve. (This should be easy for you)

Note that since $M$ is not a manifold, the set of all tangent vectors is not a linear space, thus calling it *tangent space* may be a bit misleading.

---

$M$ is a cone. It has the parametrization
$$
M = \phi\bigl([0,\pi),\mathbb R\bigr),\qquad \phi(\theta,s) = (s\sin\theta,s\cos\theta,s).
$$